# How to resolve Error 403 python web app is stopped on azure

Tags: python, azure, kudu

I have a python web app running fine on azure. I can access it using the url `http://<name>.azurewebsites.net/api/v1/`. In python project, I also have logging file where I am saving all the logs of the project.

Previously I used to access the log file using the `kudu console` but now when I try to open the kudu console, I get below error:

[image]

But in actual the web app is running. I am not able to access the kudu console. How can I access it to view my log file and other files inside the project. Please help. Thanks

Comment: Please share the sitename (https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Reporting-your-site-name-without-posting-it-publicly) and the UTC time of the issue.   This is neither quota nor site stopped, the result would be different if such.

Answer (score 0):

You may be running into [`Quota issues`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-monitor) if your site is in SHARED mode. Try upgrading to STANDARD infrastructure mode.

Comment: Okay so this means that under free subscription, I will not be able to use kudu console.?

Comment: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/plans/ you can use. in this case quota is exceeded

Answer (score 0):

You may try to access KUDU by appending your AAD details in the URL.

For eg: `https://<name>.scm.azurewebsites.net/@XXX.onmicrosoft.com` where XXX is the name for your directory.

> How to get the directory details?

[image]

Click on "**Directory + Subscription**" tab. It will display the details on the directory you are logged in.

Comment: Thankyou how can I know the name of the directory XXX

Comment: You can click on "Directory+Subscription" tab adjacent to your name on the top bar of the portal. I have added it in answer.